# How to join multiple lines into one line with VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Sublime Text 3, having multiple cursors on several lines and joining them with CMD+J results in a single line:

[image]

However, the same operation in VS Code (CTRL+J), results in half the number of initial lines (in this case 3 / 2 = 1.5 ≈ 2):

[image]

Is there a way to join all lines into one line in VS Code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a command `editor.action.joinLines` which doesn't have a default keybinding.  When you trigger it, you get the result you want.

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+j",  // or your keybinding
  "command": "editor.action.joinLines"
}
```

No need for a cursor on the multiple lines, just select the lines you want to join and trigger the command (either with some keybinding or in the Command Palette).

Comment: Regarding the keybinding - I've bound `editor.action.joinLines` to CTRL+J. But my mistake was, that I was adding the multiple cursors, instead of simple selecting all rows. Thank you very much.

Comment: Odd that the outcome is different.  Doesn't seem like it should be.

Comment: In Sublime Text it isn't, but in VS Code it is.

Comment: yeah usually I also use multiple cursor and it doesn't merge all to 1 line like in sublime / intellij idea